# Get daily average pr month when some days are missing?

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have this query which finds the daily average per month:

```
select avg(d.dayilyCount)
from (
select count(*) as dayilyCount, timestamp as dt, strftime('%d-%m-%Y', timestamp / 1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') as dmy 
from T group by dmy
) d 
group by strftime('%m-%Y', d.dt / 1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')
```

The problem is that it dosent account for days that are empty. How do I solve this?

E.g: If there are 28 days in January and only 20 days have data. It will only count and average the 20 days with 8 days missing.

Comment: Isn't it more accurate to compute that way than dividing by 28 when there are 20 days data?

Comment: Yes but in my case a day without anything should account as 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  SUM(d.dayilyCount) / (SELECT
    julianday('now', 'start of month', '+1 month', '-1 day') - julianday('now', 'start of month') + 1) as mon_avg
FROM (SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS dayilyCount,
  timestamp AS dt,
  strftime('%d-%m-%Y', timestamp / 1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') AS dmy
FROM T
GROUP BY dmy) d
GROUP BY strftime('%m-%Y', d.dt / 1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime');
```